# Custom Total in Tableau

Tags: tableadapter, tableau-api

how to do a custom total formula that will give me a % difference between the two columns and not the sum of what is in that column?

I have tried using this formula but it doesn't work. From this article https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/custom-grand-total-show-different-measure-than-table

```
IF [Size] > 1
THEN SUM(Sales)
ELSE SUM(Sales)/TOTAL(SUM(Sales))
END
```

Comment: Do you want a percent difference across the same column or a percent difference across the values in two different columns?

Comment: Have a look at [How to calculate the percent difference between two categories from the same dimension?](https://community.tableau.com/thread/158332)